# React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'match.params.id' and 'match.params.type'. Either include them or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router-v4

Hey guys ı make movie app with movie database api. When route detail page ı am check the react router props match.params and fetching data with axios like that :

**Router**

```
<Route exact path="/:type/detail/:id" component={DetailPage} />
```

Example :

http://localhost:3000/movie/detail/524434

http://localhost:3000/tv/detail/85552

I get this issue on terminal

```
WARNING in src/Components/DetailPage.js
  Line 17:8:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'match.params.id' and 'match.params.type'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

**DetailPage.js**

```
const DetailPage = ({ match }) => {
    
const [detail, setDetail] = useState([]);

    //Example api url 
    
    /* https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=b6a36190fedc206b2be58a35c9b08e95 */
/* https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/${id}?api_key=b6a36190fedc206b2be58a35c9b08e95 */


useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${match.params.type}/${match.params.id}?api_key=b6a36190fedc206b2be58a35c9b08e95`)
        .then((response) => { setDetail(response.data); });
}, [])

const url = `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${detail.backdrop_path}`;

return (

    <React.Fragment >
        {detail ?
            <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url("${url}")` }} className='background-image'>
                <div className=" linear  px-5 ">
                    <div className=" d-flex justify-content-center py-5 px-5">
                        <div className=" responsive  text-white d-flex justify-content-center align-items-md-center align-items-xl-start flex-sm-column flex-lg-row px-5 ">
                            <div className=" poster-card card col-md-4" >
                                {detail.poster_path && <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${detail.poster_path}`} alt="" className="card-image-top" />}
                            </div>
                            <div className="content  col-md-8 ps-sm-5">
                                <h1>{detail.name ? detail.name : detail.title}</h1>
                                <div className="info d-flex mt-3">
                                    <span className='me-3' >{detail.release_date}   </span>
                                    <ul className='d-flex list-unstyled flex-wrap' >{detail.genres && detail.genres.map((genres) => (<li key={genres.id} className='ms-2' > {genres.name}  </li>))}</ul>
                                </div>
                                <div className="rate ">
                                    <CircularProgressbar value={detail.vote_average * 10} text={`${detail.vote_average * 10}%`} styles={{ path: { stroke: '#21d07a', transition: 'stroke-dashoffset 0.5s ease 0s' }, text: { fill: '#ffff', fontSize: '25px' } }} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="mt-4">
                                    <span className='fst-italic text-secondary h5' >{detail.tagline}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div className="overview mt-4">
                                    {detail.overview && <h4>Overview</h4>}
                                    {<p className='text-break' > {detail.overview}</p>}
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            : <div className="spinner-border" role="status"> <span className="visually-hidden">Loading...</span></div>


           }
            {detail.id && <Cast type={match.params.type} id={detail.id} />}
        </React.Fragment>
    )

};

export default DetailPage;
```

Console error :

```
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
undefined:1 GET https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/undefined 404
```

**For check, clone my repository
[visit repository](https://github.com/egecanyldrm/movie_app)**

Answer (score 0):

detail variable is undefined on first render, so you may want to wait until it is populated to actually render your UI. Also, you need to update the dependencies for useEffect.

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const DetailPage = ({ match }) => {

  const [detail, setDetail] = useState();

  //Example api url 

  /* https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=b6a36190fedc206b2be58a35c9b08e95 */
  /* https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/${id}?api_key=b6a36190fedc206b2be58a35c9b08e95 */


  useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${match.params.type}/${match.params.id}?api_key=b6a36190fedc206b2be58a35c9b08e95`)
        .then((response) => { setDetail(response.data); });
  }, [match.params.id, match.params.type])

  const url = `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${detail.backdrop_path}`;

  if (!detail ) {
    return null
  }

  return (

      <React.Fragment >
        {detail ?
            <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url("${url}")` }} className='background-image'>
              <div className=" linear  px-5 ">
                <div className=" d-flex justify-content-center py-5 px-5">
                  <div className=" responsive  text-white d-flex justify-content-center align-items-md-center align-items-xl-start flex-sm-column flex-lg-row px-5 ">
                    <div className=" poster-card card col-md-4" >
                      {detail.poster_path && <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${detail.poster_path}`} alt="" className="card-image-top" />}
                    </div>
                    <div className="content  col-md-8 ps-sm-5">
                      <h1>{detail.name ? detail.name : detail.title}</h1>
                      <div className="info d-flex mt-3">
                        <span className='me-3' >{detail.release_date}   </span>
                        <ul className='d-flex list-unstyled flex-wrap' >{detail.genres && detail.genres.map((genres) => (<li key={genres.id} className='ms-2' > {genres.name}  </li>))}</ul>
                      </div>
                      <div className="rate ">
                        <CircularProgressbar value={detail.vote_average * 10} text={`${detail.vote_average * 10}%`} styles={{ path: { stroke: '#21d07a', transition: 'stroke-dashoffset 0.5s ease 0s' }, text: { fill: '#ffff', fontSize: '25px' } }} />
                      </div>
                      <div className="mt-4">
                        <span className='fst-italic text-secondary h5' >{detail.tagline}</span>
                      </div>
                      <div className="overview mt-4">
                        {detail.overview && <h4>Overview</h4>}
                        {<p className='text-break' > {detail.overview}</p>}
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            : <div className="spinner-border" role="status"> <span className="visually-hidden">Loading...</span></div>


        }
        {detail.id && <Cast type={match.params.type} id={detail.id} />}
      </React.Fragment>
  );

};

export default DetailPage;
```

Comment: Thanks for help terminal issue is gone but ı am publish the project and detail page is not working. I get  issue on console Can you check ? Take anyone movie or tv series  For visit : https://movie-app.egecanyildirim.com/